# Why doesn't powershell script from net-core 3.1 work in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

I have a net-core 3.1 project which runs powershell scripts. It works fine on win10, but not on win7. I get the errorr message "Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'c' doesn't exist". If I run the same powershell command directly in powershell, it works fine on win7 also, it is just from the c# code it doesn't work. I have referenced both Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK and System.Management.Automation version 7.0.0-rc.1. This simple console app shows the problem. Works on win10, but not on win7. Any suggestions?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            runspace.Open();
            using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.Runspace = runspace;
                ps.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser");
                ps.AddScript(@"$PSVersionTable.PSVersion | write-output; get-childitem -path c:\temp");

                var commandResults = ps.Invoke();

                Console.WriteLine($"PS command result {commandResults.Count} lines");
                foreach (var commandResult in commandResults)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(commandResult);
                }
                if (ps.Streams.Error.Count != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Errors:");
                    foreach (var error in ps.Streams.Error)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Finished");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me on Windows 10 servers either. My applications run as ApplicationPoolIdentity users. :(